# Generating a Random Number for HTML

Tags: html, random, numbers, generator

I am trying to generate a random number between two values that can be changed to whatever I choose. On the load of the page, I want the number to be shown in the body of my site.

Thanks!

Comment: client-side (would require javascript) or serverside? What have you tried?

Comment: @GitaarLAB I assumed client side just because I see no reason that you would want to do this server side unless you wanted to put it in a database or something...?

Comment: Were any of these answers satisfactory? If so, please mark one with an accepted checkmark and upvote.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me like you'd prefer to have the whole page written for you, so here you go. I added some very basic styling. Hope you don't mind.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showRandomNumber(){
                document.getElementById("myNumber").innerHTML = rando(5, 10);
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            #myNumber{
                font-size:100px;
                text-align:center;
                margin:50px auto;
                font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="showRandomNumber();">
        <div id="myNumber"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question was pretty vague about what you needed but here is a Javascript solution that generates a random number between two variables and then sets a `<div>` content to that:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BenedictLewis/xmPgR/

JS:

```
var link = document.getElementById('getNumber'); // Gets the link
link.onclick = getNumber; // Runs the function on click

function getNumber() {
    var minNumber = 0; // The minimum number you want
    var maxNumber = 100; // The maximum number you want
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNumber + 1) + minNumber); // Generates random number
    $('#myNumber').html(randomnumber); // Sets content of <div> to number
    return false; // Returns false just to tidy everything up
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myNumber"></div> <!-- Your number will appear in here -->
<a href="no-javascript.html" id="getNumber">Get number</a> <!-- Link to get number. If the user has no JS enabled it will redirect to no-javascript.html -->
```

Comment: Say you want a random number/entry in a matrix, how should one write it?

Answer (score 3):

> I have done this using javascript,it will generate random numbers between 0-9.Here is the code.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="one"></p>
<button onclick="random()">Random</button>

<script>
 function random(){

document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}
</script>

</body>
```

> If you want output between numbers for example between 1-10 , just edit

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

> Hope this will help you.Thank you